# A step in proof of Burnside's Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

I am reading the proof of Burnside's Theorem and it uses the following lemma in the online notes. page $70$ of - https://www.college-de-france.fr/media/jean-pierre-serre/UPL2937151343298039815_1___Groupes_finis.pdf.

> Let $s \in G-\{1\}$ and $p$ be a prime. Let the cardinality of conjugacy class of $s$ be $c(s)=p^\alpha$, for some $\alpha$.
>
> Then $\exists$ $N\lhd G $ and  $N\neq G$, such that,
>
> If $ \phi : G\rightarrow G/N$ be the natural homomorphism, then $\phi (s) \in Z(G/N)$, where $Z(G/N)$ is the center of $G/N$.

Proof: Let $r_{G}$ be the character of regular representation of G.
Therefore $$r_{G}(s)=\sum \chi(1)\chi(s)=0$$ where the sum is over all the irreducible characters of G.

Now, $$1+\sum_{\chi \neq 1} \chi(1)\chi(s)=0$$
$\implies$
$$1/p+\sum_{\chi \neq 1} (\chi(1)\chi(s))/p=0$$
$\implies$
$$-1/p=\sum_{\chi \neq 1} (\chi(1)\chi(s))/p$$

> $\implies$ $-1/p$ isn't algebraic integer .

How is the last step justified? How do we know that $-1/p$ isn't an algebraic integer?

Comment: If $f(-1/p)=0$ for some monic integer-coefficient polynomial $f$ of degree $n$ then multiplying by $p^n$ and reducing mod $p$ yields $(-1)^n\equiv0$, a contradiction.

Comment: Ah, thanks. So it is true in general and the previous steps had nothing to do with it?

Comment: Yep, this is purely a fact of number theory: the intersection of rational numbers and algebraic integers is precisely the ("rational") integers.

Comment: ("rational") integers,  meaning?

Comment: Meaning just integers. (In algebraic number theory, the term "integer" could apply to any element of a ring of integers of a number field, and "rational integer" refers to the usual ones.)

Comment: hmm.. thanks. I got distracted by what I thought was a "therefore" (donc) in the notes and thought that this was a consequence of the previous steps.. @anon : Can you please migrate your comment to answer so that I can select it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment by @anon

If $f(−1/p)=0$, $f(−1/p)=0$ for some monic integer-coefficient polynomial $f$ of degree $n$ then multiplying by $p^n$ and reducing mod $p$ yields $(−1)^n≡0$ then,  $(−1)≡0$ or $1≡0$, a contradiction.